# What is a collaborative algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, terminology, distributed-computing

What is a **collaborative algorithm**? Is there a scientifically citable reference?

---

Details:

- I found [many articles about collaborative algorithms](http://scholar.google.de/scholar?q=%22collaborative%20algorithm%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5), but none (or other websites) with a definition.
- I am actually looking for a term to describe distributed algorithms where each instance has all information at the beginning and can complete the whole task on its own, but the instances help each other whenever they have solved a sub-problem, so the other instances do not have to redo the work (hence "collaboration"). I picked up this terminology in [A Collaborative Approach for Multi-Threaded SAT Solving](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10766-009-0097-6). Do you think the term "collaborative algorithm" is suitable for this? If not, do you know of a better term?

Comment: Care to comment on the -1 or how I can improve my question?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no scientifically citable references.

All parallel/distributed programming is "collaborative" in a sense that several threads/nodes are collaborating on the same big task.

*distributed algorithms where.. instances help each other whenever they have solved a sub-problem* - even some web application clusters fit your description: individual cluster nodes "solve subproblems" and store the "solutions" in a distributed in-RAM storage (such as memcached or cassandra or many others) thus helping each other.

Comment: Good point, any communication can be considered collaboration (+1) What I want to communicate is that each instance could solve the whole problem on its own, given enough time. I believe that's what my citet papers meant, but it's difficult to say without them defining "collaborative algorithm" :(

Comment: _each instance could solve the whole problem on its own, given enough time_ - again, this applies to almost any computing cluster / distributed system. Look at the folding@home for example: given enough time, a single PC could calculate the shapes of all the proteins. However, adding nodes to the system reduces the time to solve the problem.

Comment: Hm, if I'm looking at Lynch's Distributed Algorithms, it seems most problems are only solved by multiple processes together (or there is no problem to be solved cosidering one node in isolation). In practice, you might be right, but that's even more a reason to give this distinction some name/terminology.

Comment: You’re looking at the book that has been published in 1996. Nowdays, the problems covered in this book are either irrelevant at all (such as leader election in a token ring network), or only relevant to some narrow areas (packet routing, or low-level system programming for shared memory clusters). While most software developers doing parallel/distributed programming (including those developing for shared memory clusters) are spending their time on different problems.
Disclaimer: I only worked on some medium-scale clusters build with commodity servers. I’ve never developed for supercomputers.

Comment: Do you know http://www.amazon.com/Distributed-Algorithms-Message-Passing-Systems-Michel/dp/3642381227? I have only glanced over it, but the classes of algorithms covered there also include the ones from Lynch's book...

Answer (score 0):

I think the term "collaborative algorithm" is not formal.
Actually the term "algorithm" itself is not really formal,
as far as I remember. I guess algorithm can be formalized as 
"a program which runs on a Turing machine". I think I've seen
this definition somewhere.

So yes, I guess all in all the term you coined makes sense, but you 
need to define it somehow yourself (either formally or informally).

Not sure what your background is but ... OK, in scientific papers
different authors sometimes use same terms/concepts for denoting 
different things and sometimes they use different terms for
denoting the same thing.

Also, even though computer science papers are scientific not 
all terms in them are formally defined. So I wouldn't draw
too many conclusions based on these papers unless I am familiar
to a decent extent with all of them or unless some of them
are considered really remarkable and widely accepted as
a de-facto standard in a particular sub-field or field.